# Define a new number format?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010, microsoft-onenote-2013

I'd like to define a new number format in OneNote like I do in Word 2010. Is this possible?

[image: Word Define Number]

Comment: From the trials of what I have done - this functionality is not available in OneNote 2013. And if you intend to customize your document to such an extent - I'd say that a note taking application is not a good choice - rather choose a word processing software like MS Word!

Comment: I've gotten close using the customize styles in the Onetastic addon for OneNote. Just my Q is changed to a lower case Q.

Comment: Here is link to the addon. [link](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?i=update-for-onetastic-1-3-0#custom-styles]